# Proper Decimal Problem?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    float M=2E30, G=6.67E-11, m=6E24, r=1.5E11;

    float F= (G*M*m)/(r*r);

    printf("F is %f",F);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to print the value of `F` with two decimal precision. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Short answer: replace %f with %.2f.  If that's not exactly what you want, look into the various modifiers available in printf.

Answer (score 4):

For two decimal precision, change your printf statement as below

```
printf("F is %.2f", F);
```

read [this](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?printf+3) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

`printf("F is %0.2f",F);`

The `0` in `%0.2f` tells that the output need not to be right justified and the `2` after the decimal tells that there should be only 2 digits after the decimal in the output. Basically `%0.nf` allows us to set a precision of n digits after the decimal in the output.

Hope this helps.